# Struggling with impacket installation

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-module, psexec, impacket

I'm trying to install impacket and it always give me an error. My pip and python version is same (Python 2.7.18 and pip 20.3.4 from /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip (python 2.7)).

I checked into my repository and impacket already installed under my python3. I tried to uninstall and install it using pip2 but still give me bunch of error.

I have watched all the tutorial, and follow all solution but seems not working. Is there anyone willing to help me to fix this issue? Thank you

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.